# Implementing two Persian DateTimePickers in same activity

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker, persian

I want to Implementing two Persian DateTimePickers in same activity but two method that named "onTimeSet" & "onDateSet are defined once...

how i use these methods two time in one activity for each TimePickers and DatePickers ?

In addition i use this library: https://github.com/mohamad-amin/PersianMaterialDateTimePicker

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.mohamadamin.persianmaterialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;
import com.mohamadamin.persianmaterialdatetimepicker.time.RadialPickerLayout;
import com.mohamadamin.persianmaterialdatetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog;
import com.mohamadamin.persianmaterialdatetimepicker.utils.PersianCalendar;

public class TimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,
        View.OnClickListener {


    //VARIABLE DEFINITION
    Button btn_start_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_time_button);
    Button btn_start_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_date_button);
    TextView txt_start_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_time_textview);
    TextView txt_start_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_date_textview);
    PersianCalendar persianCalendar1 = new PersianCalendar();
    PersianCalendar persianCalendar2 = new PersianCalendar();
    private boolean mode24Hours;


    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog1;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog1;
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog2;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.start_time_button: {
                timePickerDialog1 = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        TimeActivity.this,
                        persianCalendar1.get(PersianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        persianCalendar1.get(PersianCalendar.MINUTE),
                        mode24Hours
                );
                timePickerDialog1.setThemeDark(false);
                timePickerDialog1.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickerDialog");

                /*timePickerDialog1.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        Log.d( "TimePickerDialog", "Dialog was cancelled");
                    }
                });*/
                break;
            }
            case R.id.start_date_button: {
                datePickerDialog1 = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        TimeActivity.this,
                        persianCalendar1.getPersianYear(),
                        persianCalendar1.getPersianMonth(),
                        persianCalendar1.getPersianDay()
                );
                datePickerDialog1.setThemeDark(false);
                datePickerDialog1.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickerDialog");
                break;
            }
            case R.id.end_time_button: {

                timePickerDialog2 = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        TimeActivity.this,
                        persianCalendar2.get(PersianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        persianCalendar2.get(PersianCalendar.MINUTE),
                        mode24Hours
                );
                timePickerDialog2.setThemeDark(false);
                timePickerDialog2.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickerDialog");
                break;
            }
            case R.id.end_date_button: {
                datePickerDialog2 = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        TimeActivity.this,
                        persianCalendar2.getPersianYear(),
                        persianCalendar2.getPersianMonth(),
                        persianCalendar2.getPersianDay()
                );
                datePickerDialog2.setThemeDark(false);
                datePickerDialog2.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickerDialog");
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        String time = "You picked the following time: " + hourOfDay + "h" + minute;
        txt_start_time.setText(time);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String date = "You picked the following date: " + dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year;
        txt_start_date.setText(date);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two listeners

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener one_dateListener,two_dateListener;
```

Listener Implementation as follows:

```
one_dateListener= new OnDateSetListener(){

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                          ...

                }
            }

        };
        two_dateListener= new OnDateSetListener(){
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                .....
            }
        };
```

Use these listeners in your dialog:

```
int DATE_PICKER_TO = 0;
int DATE_PICKER_FROM = 1;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch(id){
        case DATE_PICKER_ONE:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, one_dateListener, from_year, from_month, from_day); 
            case DATE_PICKER_TWO:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, two_dateListener, to_year, to_month, to_day);
    }
        return null;
}
```